# How can I fire Onclick event programmatically?

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I have a custom view with 2 linear layouts: the first is the view's header and the second is the the details view.

In the custom view, the OnClickListener of the header Linearlayout is already defined: when it fires, it collapses/expandes the second linearlayout.

What I want to do is to add more functionalities to my header's OnClickListener event (i.e.: collapse/expand the second layout and show a Toast).

I can't modify the source code of the custom view. I tried to set a new OnClickListener but it hides the initial event (collapse/expand).

How should I implement this?

The source code of My Custom View:

```
public class ExpandoLayout extends ViewGroup
{
    /* some declarations */
    private Linearlayout header;
    private linearlayout footer;

    /* some code */
    @override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
    header= new LinearLayout(context);
    header.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                toggleExpand();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to add some code to the already defined OnClickListener event in my activity.
Something like that:

```
public class myActivity extends Activity {
private Linearlayout myCustomView;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.rsdetail);
    myCustomView= (MyCustomView) findViewById(R.id.expanded);

    myCustomView.getChildAt(0).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(v instanceof LinearLayout)
            {
                v.performClick();

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ExpandoOnClickListener", 2000).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code.......

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simple solution would be to get original OnClickListener and then fire it in new one:

```
final OnClickListener preDefinedListener = myCustomView.getChildAt(0).getOnClickListner();

myCustomView.getChildAt(0).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v instanceof LinearLayout)
        {
            preDefinedListener.onClick(v); // calls default (defined by MyCustomView)

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ExpandoOnClickListener", 2000).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Sadly, `View` does not have `getOnClickListner()`, but I guess you can use [reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/) to get it. It is stored in the [field](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) `mOnClickListener` ([source](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/View.java)).

This is how you can get `OnClickListener` defined for your layout:

```
OnClickListener tmpOnClickListener = null;
try {
    Class<View> cls = (Class<View>) Class.forName("android.view.View");
    Field fld = cls.getDeclaredField("mOnClickListener");
    fld.setAccessible(true); // because it is protected

    tmpOnClickListener = (OnClickListener) fld.get(myCustomView.getChildAt(0));

    fld.setAccessible(false); // restore it's original property
} catch (SecurityException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} 

final OnClickListener preDefinedListener = tmpOnClickListener;

if (preDefinedListener != null) {
    myCustomView.getChildAt(0).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View paramView) {
            preDefinedListener.onClick(paramView);

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ExpandoOnClickListener", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
});
```

I didn't really bother to handle all exception correctly, but it's enough to get the idea.
It might look messy, but it's actually just 5 lines of new code to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot Vladimir :) it works for me fine.
I just want to ask you a question: is Reflection expansive in terms of memory and/or processor??

Comment: no problem =) well, getting fields and invoking methods via reflection is more expensive than doing it "normally", but in this case the difference is so minor it won't affect anything. There is a caveat, however - since the field is accessed by name, if its name changes (which probably won't happen) this code will stop working - it won't crash, but `NoSuchFieldException` will be thrown, and `preDefinedListener` will end up `null`, which leaves listener set for layout intact.

Answer (score 89):

You can programmatically raise click event on a View to call it's `OnClickListener` as below:

```
view.performClick();
```

Now if you call this on your second layout under first layout's *OnClickListener* then i hope it should do the magic

Comment: When I do this. It gives me a 06-05 10:29:59.470: E/AndroidRuntime(7518): java.lang.StackOverflowError

Comment: can you post your full logcat exception

Comment: are you calling `myCustomView.performClick()`? If, so you need to call as `myCustomView.getChildAt(0).performClick()`

Comment: 06-05 10:58:10.440: E/AndroidRuntime(8044): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-05 10:58:10.440: E/AndroidRuntime(8044): java.lang.StackOverflowError
06-05 10:58:10.440: E/AndroidRuntime(8044):  at java.util.HashMap.containsKey(HashMap.java:330)
06-05 10:58:10.440: E/AndroidRuntime(8044):  at android.provider.Settings$NameValueCache.getString(Settings.java:599)
06-05 10:58:10.440: E/AndroidRuntime(8044):  at android.provider.Settings$System.getString(Settings.java:731)
06-05 10:58:10.440: E/AndroidRuntime(8044):  at android.provider.Settings$System.getInt(Settings.java:780)06-05

Comment: here it is : expandedCustomer= (ExpandoLayout) viewr.findViewById(R.id.expandedClient);
        expandedCustomer.getChildAt(0).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v instanceof LinearLayout)
    {
     expandedCustomer.getChildAt(0).performClick();
    
     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ExpandoOnClickListener", 2000).show();
    }
   }
  });

Comment: the way you are calling will definitely crash because its calling itself in a continuous loop - just like a black-hole **:)**. Instead of using performCLick on `getChildAt(0)` inside OnCLickListener, it should be second layout or `getChildAt(1)` (if any)

Answer (score 9):

Since SDK 15 you can just call method:

```
view.callOnClick()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot modify the code of CustomView then you have the below option.

- Extend the CustomView.
- Override the onClick() method and bind this as a Listener to the first layout.
- Inside onClick() first call super.onClick() then add your additional functionality below.

This way you are keeping the existing code and adding additional functionality as well.

Comment: the OnClickListener event is defined as Anonymous Listener. How can I override it??